# Handle un-checked radio boxes in cherrypy

Tags: forms, web-services, validation, radio-button, cherrypy

In my application, I have two options each as a radio button:

```
<form action = "handle_radio" method="post">
<input type = "radio" name = "model_download_option" value = "1"> Option1 </input>
<input type = "radio" name = "model_download_option" value = "2"> Option2 
</input>
<input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

Once the user clicks submit, it redirects to one end-point in my cherrypy code. Something like:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def handle_radio(model_download_option):
    <do something>
```

However, if the user doesn't check any option, then I get a *404 Error : Missing parameters: model_download_option*.

However, I would just want the page to reload. ***What is the right way to handle such un-checked radio boxes***

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix : **Default arguments**

In my case , the method would be defined something like:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def handle_radio(model_download_option=''):
    <do something>
```

This prevents the missing parameter error and by checking for empty string we can shift the control to desired behavior in case of no-input